# IIS Cannot Get Access to an Excel File for Users, But is OK for Me. Why?

Tags: excel, office-automation

I have a program running as a service in IIS in Windows Server 2008 R2.  The program has no problem creating a report in Excel. The problem occurs when it tries to get access to the Excel the that it has just created. This gives the users a 80070005 error right at this line of code:

```
Excel.Application excelSS = null;
excelSS = new Excel.Application(); <-- Error
```

Because at that point, the program has not tried to get access to the Excel file just yet, I believe the problem is not related to lack of access rights to the file.  I believe the problem may have to do with locating the Excel program.  This may have to do with the fact that the Excel is 32-bit and the Windows operating system is in 64-bit.  I am not sure.

The strange thing is that I have no problem viewing the Excel report through IIS.  Another IT guy also has no problem doing this.  But normal users all have this problem trying to do the exact same thing.  This all points to the high probability that this problem is related to "access rights".  If it has to do with the setup of Excel, I would assume that everyone including me would have the same problem.  This is very puzzling.

I have already tried all the tips that I can find in Internet:

- Confirm that the Application-Pools in IIS uses IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool user account.
- Add a "Desktop" folder in system32 and in SysWOW64 under config\systemprofile and make sure the IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool user account has read/write access to those folders.
- Run DCOM-Config, and assign local access/launch/activation rights to IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool under COM-Security. And make sure both 32-bit and 64-bit DCOM-Config get these settings.
- Because of the fact that the users use "Windows Authentication" to run the program in IIS, I also make sure that the users can use their own user account to get access to the folder in IIS server that stores the Excel file.
- I even go as far as adding IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool to local admin user group.

The only tip that I cannot try is the fact that I cannot find "Microsoft Excel Application" listed in DCOM-Config program (Component Services --> Computers --> My Computer --> DCom Config).  I am supposed to add launch/activate access rights to IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool to "Microsoft Excel Application" in that list.  But somehow "Microsoft Excel Application" is not in the list.  I have tried looking for it in DCOM-Config in both System32 and SysWOW64 folders. This "seems" like where the problem is. But I am not sure about this because of the fact that I have no problem viewing the Excel report using my user account. If there was something wrong with the settings in Excel, I would think that none of us could view the Excel report.

I didn't have this problem when I had that program in Windows Server 2003 R2 - 32bit, or in Windows XP 32-bit.

I understand the issue about Microsoft want people not to use Office Automation in Windows Server 2008.  And Microsoft wants people to use XML or something like that.  But I also understand that people have tried this and can work around this.  Because I am not the developer of that program, I really don't want to start changing that program.  Therefore, I would like to be able to get the existing program to work.

Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Jay Chan

Answer (score 2):

Turned out this problem has to do with access rights.  Seem like ASP.NET was running under the user's authentication (not surprising because I have set the web service to use "Windows Authentication").  And the user doesn't have permission to run Excel directly at the server.  The solution is to use a special domain user account: (1) Assign the special user account as the local admin, (2) Assign the special user account as the "Specific user" for "ASP.NET Impersonation" for the web service.

I have a feeling that the special user account was somehow embedded in that specific web service. Therefore, the fix that I mentioned above may or may not work for other people. Unfortunately I don't know if this is true or not because I was not the developer of that web service.  And I cannot find any where in the web service mentioning anything related to that specific user account.

I am glad that this is fixed.

Jay Chan

Comment: I also need to change "Identity" of "Microsoft Excel Application" from "The launching user" to "The interactive user".  That is changed in DCOM-Config --> Component Services --> Computers --> My Computer --> DCOM Config --> Microsoft Excel Application --> Right click it and go to properties

Comment: Is this the answer for this question as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49208958/is-it-possible-to-resolve-a-dcom-interactive-user-permission-error-when-using-d